# Flutter FCM CastMap<dynamic, dynamic, String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

When sending notifications, I have a nested data as follows:

```
    message = {
                "notification": {
                    "title": "app notification",
                    "body": "new message!"
                },
                "data": {
                    "info":{
                        "id": message_id,
                        "message": message,
                        "img": img
                }
               }
              }
```

The reason I do this is because sometimes the `img` is null and I want to send that information as well. If I place it outside of `info`, the `null` values get dropped.

When I check the `runtimeType` of the the notification data, I get `CastMap<dynamic, dynamic, String, dynamic>` and I don't even know what kind of data type that is. I am trying to convert it to `Map<String, dynamic>` by doing `Map<String, dynamic>.from(event)`, but it keeps telling me

`Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>`

What exactly is `CastMap<dynamic, dynamic, String, dynamic>` and how can i extract `event['data']['info']` from it?

Comment: how about `json.decode(event['data']['info'])` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe That worked. Thank you. If you post your solution, I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `json.decode` to return it as a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

```
json.decode(event['data']['info'])
```